# What is the short cut to extract strings from Android code into the strings.xml file in Intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse I used to use a combination (first press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>S</kbd>) to extract strings into `strings.xml` but I could not find it on Intellij. How to do this on Intellij?

Comment: How about Android Studio 2.2.3?

Comment: is there any way to do it programatically?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> combination.

[More info](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/extracting-hard-coded-string-literals.html)

Comment: normally I'm using that combination but I could not see it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is always good to see familiar face. :) Thank you. Vay gardas isime cok yaradi.

Comment: i think way to extract text in android studio !!

Comment: For me, only the left ALT + Enter works, not with the ALT key on the right side. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Goto Android studio 'Help' -> Find action -> type "extract string resource"

You will find a ON / OFF button. Switch on the option.

Comment: All that does is allow me to turn it on/off. But Alt-Enter still does not work on 2.2.3.

Comment: It's working for me in 2.2.3. Make sure to select the text without the enclosing quotes. For some reason when you select the string with the quotes the option does not appear in the menu. Or you can just click on the string without selecting text. It should work then too.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a menu with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> but you do not see the option `extract string resource` it might be because you are not **in** the string but **behind** the quotation mark.

The cursor has to be inside the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same thing.

Paramasivam Vijay Anand Had it right.

Android Studio 2.2.3 you can go to help and turn on the Extract string resource.
However, Alt+enter does not extract the resource when clicking the text in the Design tab, it works for me when I clicked to the Activity_main and then selected the text there. Quotes didn't seem to matter.