# Extract string resource suggestion with key from java class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How can I extract string resource directly from Java class which suggest key itself, as we do from xml.

Comment: I think your question is not clear. please enter some more details

Comment: @vm345 Edited question

Comment: All guys thought i am asking about popup, but it's not that.

Comment: this [link](https://medium.com/@q2ad/android-automatic-string-extraction-ce7431d80147) may be useful for you

Answer (score 2):

Click `ctrl+shift+a` and type intensions and select the first item,Or click file-> settings -> Editor ->intensions. Enable extract string resources.

[image]

Comment: Can you put an screenshot please, i could not find that.

Comment: of the intenstions screen??

Comment: Yes i could not find `extract string resources`

Comment: I added the screen shot

Comment: That is by default enabled.

Comment: Can you don the same i mentioned in question.

Comment: This did not help me

Comment: if that is enabled it should show up with alt + enter. where is it not showing up?(in toasts or logs)

Comment: You also mis-understood me

Answer (score -1):

You can do this. First hardcode the String as follows.

```
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "hardcoded string");
```

Now put the cursor top of that String (harcoded string) and press ALT + ENTER. It will show the option to Extract String resources.

Answer (score -1):

Just press alt + enter above the string.Same as in layout.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938055/is-there-a-way-to-extract-a-string-with-an-automatically-generated-resource-name